# Python3.4 + Django + Ubuntu:
unknown encoding: raw-unicode-escape

Tags: python, linux, django, python-3.x, ubuntu

I'm using a Django app on Ubuntu Trusty in a virtualenv with python 3.4 in chroot on Linux Deploy on Android 5.1.1 (Cyanogenmod 12.1). When I add an event and load the front-end, I get the following error:

> LookupError at /: unknown encoding: raw-unicode-escape
>   [image: LookupError]
>   How do I fix this, do I have to install some codec packages to python (if yes, which packages)?

Edit: full log:
http://pastebin.com/QH32e92i

Comment: You see that link at the bottom of your error, saying "Switch to copy-and-paste view"? **Click it**, then paste the actual error text here rather than a cut-off screenshot.

Comment: Thanks, updated the post

Comment: http://pastebin.com/QH32e92i

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem was related to the architecture of the os - I was using a strange distro on Linux Deploy distribution, when I switched to VirtualBox and installed an amd64 one, everything worked properly with the same code.